# PHP cURL (+ if) with Combo-box

Tags: php, if-statement, curl

How can I select via PHP cURL and make a if clause to select from a Combo-box?
This is the URL:
http://www2.olx.com.br/ai/form/0

And this is what need to be selected via cURL (using IF Clause, because categories will be selected according to my data):
[image: OLX Category]

I'm getting info via array and then transverse array to post data format:

```
$post_data = array(
'subject' => 'Title',
'body' => 'Description',
);

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
```

Also, in this same page, there is a gallery upload. How can I get my images to be uploaded there?

I'm getting data via my XML FEED, so I use SimpleXML to get all content from tags:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("feed.xml");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml); $i++) {
$pictures = $xml->imovel[$i]->pictures->picture;
}
```

--------------EDIT -> My new Curl File

```
<?php

//create array of data to be posted
$post_data = array(
'check_type_diff' => '0',
'parent_category' => '1000',
'category_group' => '1020',
'apartment_type' => '1',
'type' => 's',
'rooms' => '1',
'size' => '',
'garage_spaces' => '',
'condominio' => '',
'iptu' => '',
'subject' => 'Test',
'body' => 'Test Test',
'price' => '100.000,00',
'zipcode' => '30170-110',
'address' => '',
'map_lati' => '',
'map_long' => '',
'state' => '2',
'region' => '31',
'company_ad' => '0',
'name' => 'Test Test',
'email' => 'MyTestEmailHere@privateinfo.com',
'email_confirm' => 'MyTestEmailHere@privateinfo.com',
'phone' => '(31) 1111 1111',
'passwd' => 'EasyPw',
'passwd_ver' => 'EasyPw',
'create' => '',
);


//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection =
  curl_init('http://www2.olx.com.br/ai/verify/0');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$headers = array();

//curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);



//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .
                curl_error($curl_connection);

if(curl_errno($curl_connection))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl_connection);
}

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
 return $result;
?>
```

This is what I get when I run the code:

```
Array ( [url] => http://www2.olx.com.br/ai/form/0?s=mc1x688dd1c7a5e6c5e692969363c4f40d43ae7e03aa [content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-15 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 2906 [request_size] => 1726 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 4 [total_time] => 7.156 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 58760 [speed_download] => 8211 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 0 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 1.547 [redirect_time] => 5.609 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [redirect_url] => ) 0-
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. Are you trying to use that form via cURL and yo need to 1) Select a category and 2) Upload a image to the form?

Comment: That's it. All the rest I can handle because are normal textbox. But for selecting input (or select boxes) and upload images I have no ideia how to get it done.

Comment: Could you update the question with the code where you are completing the text boxes?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't have a code for this because I don't know how to parse this kind of data. Does it help if I post all my curl file?

Comment: Yes, I think it will help

Comment: There it go! Please, take a look in my edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things that could help you:

1. Right now you are sending the request to http://www2.olx.com.br/ai/form/0, but I you check that webpage using the Developer Tools (or something similar) you will notice that the form is defined with `action="/ai/verify/0"` so your request should be going to http://www2.olx.com.br/ai/verify/0.
2. The form has a lot of inputs (even some hidden ones) so yo could do this trick to see what info is being sent by the form:

   - Create a new webpage (eg. http://localhost/form_test/index.php)
   - Add this code to this new `<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>`
   - Go to http://www2.olx.com.br/ai/form/0 and complete the fields
   - Before submitting the form, use the Developer Tools to change the `action=` of the form to the webpage you just created
   - This way you will see all the fields sent by the form
3. Take note that some categories in the form add some extra fields.
4. In order to select the categories you could have two different approaches:

   - Make an initial cURL request and gather the categories in order to get the values that each categorie have (again, be carefull because some categories add new fields to the form)
   - Manually inspect the value of each categorie and save them in some text file to use them later.
5. I don't know if you can upload an image with this approach

**Final thoughts**

I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish here but it seems that there might be a better way.

Comment: I did all you have said and when I run the code I get http_code 200... but when I log using my browser and see if something was posted, there is nothing in the control panel :(. Take a look into the edited post.

Comment: Yup.... I had to add a Login curl before in order to get what you said working.... But now there is a problem: When there are some mistakes posting, NoCaptcha from Google Recaptcha shows up... and I can't select the box using php curl, right?

Comment: NoCaptcha is *"Tough on bots, Easy on humans"*. It is suppose to avoid what you are trying to do.

Comment: Using other languages it's possible to make a "aim" using a pattern image.... Let's see.... Hm.... Grab a picture from the box and use a "fake mouse" to "fake a click" somewhere I want. Just like fps games where people use Aimbots to shoot on virtual boxes where is actually character head. Probably PHP do not support this kind of mouse click simulation, right?

Comment: What about make a timer for each post? I tested posting 3 stuff and in the third I get captcha. If I could make a loop with a 60s timer maybe I do not get captch. What do you think?

Comment: That would probably work, the captcha triggers only when you behave like a bot. The algorithm to test if you are a bot or no is not known, but I'm sure that making 5 post per second is a clear signal you are a bot. If you wait a time between each post is probably that it will consider it a "human" behaivour. Even better, wait a random time between 50 to 150 seconds (or any range) to look like more human.

Comment: But do you know what php command would work in this case? And how this random time would be programmed?

Comment: `sleep(rand(50,150))`. Check `sleep` and `rand` on PHP documentation.

Comment: Thanks! :D Please, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361459/php-curl-loop-for-post-using-simplexml